# Django (Models): Automatically pick and return a value by the choice option

Tags: python, django

I'm building a simple sys which selects a link by given value.
So imagine a user is posting a post and he has to select the type of the post for example (old, new, classic).

And this is what I've got right now:

```
MarkerIcons = (
        # We can choose between:
        ('0', _('https://i.imgur.com/U8ddIZs.png')), # POLICE CAR2 (InUse)
        ('1', _('https://i.imgur.com/ec2VbzA.png')), # POLICE RAID
        ('2', _('https://i.imgur.com/kM9Ppou.png')), # PASSENGER_CONTROL

        # Camera's
        ('3', _('https://i.imgur.com/VDUPhLx.png')), # TRIPOD
        ('4', _('https://i.imgur.com/MpiJ8st.png')), # SPEED CAMERA & other img - https://i.imgur.com/EbItaVR.png 

        # Extra's-
        ('5', _('https://i.imgur.com/w00r7kC.png')), # ACCIDENT
        ('6', _('https://i.imgur.com/fykUX9D.png')), # TRAFFIC JAM
        ('7', _('https://i.imgur.com/ooZDKug.png')), # CONSTRUCTION_WORK
        ('8', _('CAR_STOPPED')), #

        ('9', _('OTHER')), #
        ('10', _('UNKNOWN')) #
    )
```

This is what I'm trying to use to automatically return the link from the choices.

```
marker_icon = models.CharField(choices=MarkerIcons, blank=False, null=False, max_length="40", default='0')
```

What's the correct method to select and insert the link of the choices to the Database?

I want to do something like this:
If the `CharField` default or given value is - "2", I set the current model Charfield value to `'https://i.imgur.com/kM9Ppou.png'`

But this does not work as it should, In the previous attempts I was using IntegerField, but I realized that IntegerField couldn't store link because it's a string.

This is the error which I get now:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the icon keywords instead of URLs on your model. I.e. `'police-car2'` instead of `'https://i.imgur.com/U8ddIZs.png'`, etc. Because, what if you decide to use some other icon for each marker? Or what if you decide to store those images on other server/service and you need to change URLs?

Instead, map marker icon keys to URLs when you serialize your data to return in a response.

---

Regarding your initial issue:

If you still want to implement it your way then you have to map the marker icon key to the URL explicitly. For that you could modify the `save` method on your model:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
  ...

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Pick URL from the list by key, or use the provided marker_icon value if
    # key not found (in case you pass URL directly)
    self.marker_icon = next((m[1] for m in MarkerIcons if m[0] == self.marker_icon), self.marker_icon)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Yes, in the future I will use the keywords for sure, but you see the problem is not this, I can't find the way how to set 'url' in this case, inside the charfield just by giving id as a string, for example - 2 and setting the charfield value to - https://i.imgur.com/kM9Ppou.png which comes from `('2', _('https://i.imgur.com/kM9Ppou.png')), # PASSENGER_CONTROL` which is from my choices

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: `ERRORS:
main.Reports.marker_icon: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
main.Reports.status: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
main.Reports.type: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.`

Comment: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: `ERRORS:
main.Reports.marker_icon: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
main.Reports.status: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
main.Reports.type: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
main.UserReports.reason: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.`

Comment: Ok, sorry, it was a bad idea to convert it to a dict, updated my answer